# mod_rewrite / htaccess not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

I can't get mod_rewrite to work on a client's site, it's just ignoring the .htaccess file completely.

I'm not 100% sure what flavour of Linux is being used, it seems to be CentOs.

I've checked the `httpd.conf` file and mod_rewrite is enabled. I've altered the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file to `AllowOverrides All`.

Here's the relevant contents of the `data/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
#XAMPP
#Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# XAMPP
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes


#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
#AllowOverride None
# since XAMPP 1.4:
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#
# "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# XAMPP
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

And here's the content of `data/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain">
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain
RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

My `.htaccess` file contains just this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.*$ htaccess_tester.php
</IfModule>
```

I can't find any error logs for apache.
I must be missing something somewhere...!

Comment: To identify the flavor of Linux, try `uname -a`, `cat /etc/*-release`, `lsb_release -a`, or `cat /proc/version`. Have you tried restarting Apache since making changes to its config files? You have two Virtual Hosts on the same port but on different folders. Why? Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: Is your "extra" config file being included? What about your `.htaccess` file? One way to confirm this is to introduce a deliberate parse error in each file in turn and restart Apache, checking the logs for corresponding error messages.

Comment: Your second vHost definition is missing its `ServerName`

Comment: Later versions of Apache have replaced the `Order allow,deny` configuration directive. It's essential you identify the version you're trying to use.

Comment: `uname -a` returns `Linux <servername> 2.6.18-243.el5 #1 SMP Mon Feb 7 18:47:27 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a` returns `LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.4
Codename:       Tikanga`

I've removed the second Virtual Hosts. The .htaccess file is in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain` 

I left the `ServerName` out above but it's in VirtualHosts section on the server

Comment: And yes I am restarting apache after editing.

Comment: RHEL 5.4 is from 2009. The latest update is RHEL 5.11 from September 2014. You should really update that. It's okay to obscure values (e.g., `ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`), but you shouldn't leave out entire lines from your sample if their absence will draw attention. Have you checked that you can access *any* file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydomain? As an aside, rewrites are recommended to be done in [server config files or vhost config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#htaccess) rather than .htaccess.

Comment: There's little chance anyone will be able to debug this if you've omitted important parts of the configuration. And please add your information into the question. It's too easy for it to get lost amid the comments.